# What Graphics Driver For Windows 7 32bit 1GB Ram?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, intel-graphics

I have installed Windows 7 Professional 32bit. when I want to play Counterstrike 1.6, OpenGL does not run and I cannot find a video graphics driver.

[image: PC info]

PC info:

- RAM: 1 GB
- GHz: 2. 80
- Pentium 4

I tried to find the video driver with "Intel (R) Driver Update Utility 2.2", but there was no result. How can I find the correct graphics driver?

Comment: Hold the left Windows key, press E. Locate "Computer" and right click, select "Manage", locate "Device manager", find and click "+" to the left oif "Display adapters", at new line should appear, please right click this and select "Properties", then select the /Driver\ tab. Edit your question and add information about "Driver provider" and "Driver details" - this might help us help you.

Comment: Do you have a dGPU?  Pentium 4 didn't to my knowledge have a iGPU.  If it did, feel free to go to Intel's website, and download the driver.

Comment: Driver Details  ,

display adapters
- standard VGA Graphics Adapter
.
/DRIVER\

Driver Provider : Microsoft
Driver Date     : 6/21/2006
Driver Version  : 6.1.7600.16385
Digital Signer  : Microsoft Windows

Comment: That does not answer my question

Comment: What makes you think you have Intel graphics?